# Why does my jquery function only works once?

Tags: jquery

this may sound stupid but i am a Jquery noob and I am trying to make a div tag to resize when I when swipe left and right on mobile, and I am not sure why its only executed once? can any jquery gurus here help me out !!!! thank you

here is the code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="box">
  </div>

  <script>
    $(function right(){
      // Bind the swiperightHandler callback function to the swipe event on div.box
      $( "div.box" ).on( "swiperight", swiperightHandler );

      // Callback function references the event target and adds the 'swiperight' class to it
      function swiperightHandler( event ){
        $( event.target ).addClass( "swiperight" );
      }
    });

    $(function left(){
      // Bind the swiperightHandler callback function to the swipe event on div.box
      $( "div.box" ).on( "swipeleft", swiperightHandler );

      // Callback function references the event target and adds the 'swiperight' class to it
      function swiperightHandler( event ){
        $( event.target ).addClass( "swipeleft" );
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove and add the classes

```
function swiperightHandler( event ){
  $( event.target ).removeClass('swipeleft').addClass( "swiperight" );
}
```

and

```
function swiperightHandler( event ){
  $( event.target ).removeClass('swiperight').addClass( "swipeleft" );
}
```

Comment: thx guys ! solved it i guess i need to dig into the docs now to understand why :p

Answer (score 0):

It probably is being executed more than once, `addClass` won't do anything when you call it the second time as it's already added that class to the element!

Comment: thx guys ! solved it i guess i need to dig into the docs now to understand why :p